# Flutter Android PreferenceScreen settings page

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Android has `PreferenceScreen` which provides you the consistent [Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) interface and handles a lot of `SharedPreferences` functionality on its own.

Is there anything similar in Flutter or do I have to create it by my own using custom `ListView`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So, there doesn't exist any widget like that, you will have to create it on your own and handle their action in `onChanged` or `onTap` events. For example:

#### CheckBoxPreference

[image]

```
CheckboxListTile(
  value: true,
  title: Text("This is a CheckBoxPreference"),
  onChanged: (value) {},
),
```

---

#### SwitchPreference

[image]

```
SwitchListTile(
  value: false,
  title: Text("This is a SwitchPreference"),
  onChanged: (value) {},
),
```

---

#### ListPreference

[image]

```
ListTile(
  title: Text("This is a ListPreference"),
  subtitle: Text("Subtitle goes here"),
  onTap: (){},
)
```

Answer (score 9):

In Flutter the easiest way to make a PreferenceScreen page is with a ListView and ListTiles.

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text('Enable Feature'),
        trailing: Checkbox(
          value: PrefService.getBool('feature_enabled'),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              PrefService.setBool('feature_enabled', val);
            });
          },
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            PrefService.setBool(
                'feature_enabled', !PrefService.getBool('feature_enabled'));
          });
        },
      )
    ]),
```

But you still need to listen for changes and save them.

To make that easier you can use the package `preferences`. It removes the boilerplate code and manages saving the changes. The example above would look like this with `preferences`:

```
PreferencePage([
      CheckboxPreference(
        'Enable Feature',
        'feature_enabled',
      )
    ]),
```

You can find it under https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/preferences.
For more features like subpages, hiding of preferences or more widgets look at the example.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented it using my own custom `ListView` with `ListTile`

Comment: Sorry my dumb question but whats the difference between the package preferences and sharedpreferences?

Comment: @FilipeOS shared_preferences can store key value pairs on your device and `preferences` gives you some UI Widgets for your settings page in your app which use shared_preferences

Answer (score 2):

According to my research now (I checked the https://pub.dartlang.org and other resources), the answer to your question is, no there is no page like that in Flutter (Check the [official documentation](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-access-shared-preferences)). There is one plugin to have [SharedPreferences](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/shared_preferences) which is from Flutter team, but if you check out its source code, you can see that it just does data modification. Other alternatives from other developers doesn't have anything visual too (I will keep checking, if I find one, I will edit my post).

There are some ways to do it, you can do it by calling android bridge and having android specific screen for only android (yeah I know, it doesn't make much sense) when you are with flutter or **my real answer would be** you can implement it by using list view as you mentioned and assign different child elements according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, for your information. I searched that too by myself and I thought, Settings are some very key features almost every app has got. And hoping to find a solution. Maybe I should wait and someone might come up with some solution (except building everything on your own from scratch)

Comment: There is one settings screen but it's cupertino and iOS which looks pretty ugly :) I hope someone can come up with something.

Comment: Even I saw that Settings of iOS on Github, they implemented complete iOS settings which doesn't give you any idea.